# Limit list using a button

Tags: php

I want to print the last access to my application of each user, but I want to limit this list to a specific number (that eventually will be configured by the user). Atm I can print everything, but I want to implement a button that will allow to show 5 events and them go forth. Once this is implemented do the backing as well.

However my code right now is as follows:

```
        $min = 0;
        if(count($time) > 5)
        {
            $aux = 5;
        }
        else
        {
            $aux = count($time);
        }

        if(isset($_POST['button']))
        {
            if((count($time) - $aux) > 5)
            {
                $aux = aux + 5;
                $min = $min + 5;
            }
            else
            {
                $aux = count($time);
                if(count($time) > 5)
                {
                    $min = count($time) - 5;
                }
            }

        }

        for($i = $min ; $i<$aux; $i++)
        {
            echo '<br>'.($i+1).'. '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time[$i]['time_stamp'])."\t".' por '.$ips['ip'].'<br>';
        }

        ?>

        <input name="button" type="button" id="button" onclick="access.func.php" value=">>" />
```

I can't seem to update the table, mainly because I think the button is not being called the proper way.

EDIT: The axu typo was changed.

EDIT2: $count has been changed to count($time)

Comment: What is the issue exactly? Is it that you always have the same list (instead of having the 5 next events)?

Comment: $count is another typo, should be count($time)

The issue was that I couldn't update the prints in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, there's a typo in your code.

```
 $axu = aux + 5;
```

Change that to `$aux = $aux + 5;` and let's see.

EDIT:

Put that `input button` in a `<form>` like this:

```
<form action="access.func.php" method="post">
    <input name="button" type="submit" id="button" value=">>" />
</form>
```

Comment: Cheers. But the results are still the same.

Comment: @Comum Also, ensure that you have: `$aux = $aux + 5;`

Comment: Works perfectly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Possible typo axu = aux?

```
$axu = aux + 5;
```

try

```
if((count($time) - $aux) > 5)
        {
            $aux= $aux + 5;
            $min = $min + 5;
        }
```

if its intended typo (axu) - which I believe its not according to the provided code :-> just add $ to aux

```
if((count($time) - $aux) > 5)
            {
                $axu = $aux + 5;
                $min = $min + 5;
            }
```

Comment: It was not intended, it was a typo, but I have changed it now. And I still get the same results.

Comment: @Comum can u provide me with some more data so I can debug it? Like the $time array

Comment: @Comum debugging showed also  if($count > 5) that you didn't declarated the variable.

Comment: The $time array is populated using the comand:

`"SELECT time_stamp FROM acessos WHERE userID = '$userID' ORDER BY time_stamp DESC";`

Comment: Also I've checked the count and changed it. However it is still the same.

Comment: Update the question with changed count, well is it some kind of pagination system?